# What is diffuse field equalisation?

Tags: impulse-response

I am using impulse responses from http://sound.media.mit.edu/resources/KEMAR.html

These are available as either raw or diffuse-field equalized HRTFs.

My question is: Which do I want? Raw, or diffuse-field equalized?

I am using these IRs to project single notes (generated synthetically using a ring resonator) to 12 locations around the listeners head.

π

Comment: When you are testing your system, I would strongly recommend using some stimulus besides single notes.  Much of the information that an HRTF imparts on a signal is frequency dependent.  I would first test and tweak your system with a stimulus that is spectrally rich before testing it with single notes.

Comment: @nispio: This is something I've been looking at for the last few days.  I will present it as a separate question now.

Answer (score 1):

Depends mostly on your playback headset. If it's diffuse field equalized, use the diffuse field set. For most headsets, this will be the best choice.

The only difference is overall equalization, so you can turn one into the other with a simple filter that gets applied to all HRTFs